# Is there a way to reuse an ImageData to reduce GC activity?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, getimagedata

I'm looking for a GC-friendly way to use [CanvasRenderingContext#getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). One idea is to create an ImageData once and somehow reuse it so that the getImageData would not allocate a new one. Since I need to access the raw canvas data around 60 times per second, I cannot really afford to allocate a new ImageData everytime I use getImageData. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you need to draw using anything else than the buffer's data manipulation + putImageData.

The ImageData object returned by `ctx.getImageData()` is a **copy** of the underlying canvas' buffer, it is not linked to that internal buffer by any means, and there is no way that any update to the canvas would make any change to the returned ImageData.

*Note that there are [active discussions](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5173) about doing zero copy from the canvas API to for instance WebAssembly. One idea would be to extend `getImageData()` so it "*takes a view into which bytes can be written*". But this is just at the discussion stage, and we'll probably have to wait some time to see any viable solution to this more and more common issue.*

If you were to draw only by `ctx.putImageData()` after you change the data in the ImageData though, then you could of course just keep the same ImageData and never request any new, since your ImageData would always be up to date.

Also, one quite frequent misuse of ImageData is when we want to send it to WebWorkers for processing, don't forget to transfer it by using the second parameter of `worker.postMessage()` otherwise you'd duplicate this data at each message.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer. I was really close to propose an additional parameter go getImageData myself, in order to specify a reusable buffer. It's good to see a discussion is going on about this issue. It's a must to have for 60 FPS web pages IMO.

I'm aware of the transferable concept, that's why I'm playing with buffers actually. It's just that the getImageData blocks the main process while we're trying to get the buffer to use as transferable.